# how to create CNN network for black and white images

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am doing image classification, so have a 4 different categorical black and white images with  4 different folders,  please help me how to create cnn network black and white images.
I tried like this:

```
  batch_size=16
    generator= datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "Dataset/train",
    target_size=(28,28),
    batch_size=batch_size,
            class_mode=None, 
        shuffle=False)
     Found 600 images belonging to 4 classes.
```

After image generator, I build a cnn network, but it gives some values.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu', input_shape = (28,28,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))


model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))


model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(4, activation = "softmax"))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                            optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(0.0001),
              metrics=['acc'])
model.fit_generator(
        generator,
        steps_per_epoch=200 // batch_size,
        epochs=10)
```

After I build a network, I am trying to the trained network, I give some values .please help how to build cnn network for black and white.

Epoch 1/10

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-10-51af897b4f2d> in <module>()
          2         generator,
          3         steps_per_epoch=200 // batch_size,
    ----> 4         epochs=10)

    2 frames
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py in fit_generator(model, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
        196                                      'a tuple `(x, y, sample_weight)` '
        197                                      'or `(x, y)`. Found: ' +
    --> 198                                      str(generator_output))
        199                 # build batch logs
        200                 batch_logs = {}

    ValueError: Output of generator should be a tuple `(x, y, sample_weight)` or `(x, y)`. Found: [[[[2.5500000e+02 2.5500000e+02 2.5500000e+02]
       [2.5500000e+02 2.5500000e+02 2.5500000e+02]
       [2.5500000e+02 2.5500000e+02 2.5500000e+02]
       ...
       [2.5500000e+02 2.5500000e+02 2.5500000e+02]
       [2.5500000e+02 2.5500000e+02 2.5500000e+02]
       [2.5500000e+02 2.5500000e+02 2.5500000e+02]]

      [[2.5500000e+02 2.5500000e+02 2.5500000e+02]
       [2.5500000e+02 2.5500000e+02 2.5500000e+02]
       [2.5500000e+02 2.5500000e+02 2.5500000e+02]
       ...
```

Comment: Looks like you're already doing pretty good. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: If you are using Keras for creating a classifier, check out `flow_from_directory` in `ImageDataDictionary` class. It requires you to create directories with images & with directory name as class names.

Comment: yes, Aditya, I want to create class labels. please help me on how to create class labels.

Comment: This might help, if you are using keras - https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

Comment: Thank you, Ganesh,  please help how to create cnn  Network for black and white images.